# Notifications in android

Tags: android

I am trying to get notifications onto the screen for my app but it does not work for some reason, the content being displayed is a announcement that is the last one in a list of announcements, that way the user gets the latest announcement.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);

    pbc = new ProgressBarController(getWindow().getDecorView());
    tasks = new Tasks(this, getWindow().getDecorView(), pbc, swipeRefreshLayout);
    List<Announcement> list = tasks.getAnnoucements();
    int x = list.size();
    if (x != 0) {
        String string = list.get(x - 1).title;
        String s = list.get(x - 1).body;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sf_logo_verticalhdpi)
                        .setContentTitle(string)
                        .setContentText(s);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want list of notification, You need to implement the [InboxStyled Notifications.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html)

You can also visit [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html) and [here.](http://www.androidgig.com/inbox-style-notification-like-whatsapp/)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving each notification an id. Ie:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

In your case like this:

```
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    for(int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++) {
        String string = list.get(x).title;
        String s = list.get(x).body;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sf_logo_verticalhdpi)
                        .setContentTitle(string)
                        .setContentText(s);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(i, mBuilder.build());
    }
```